# Installing old version of Readxl readxl_0.1.1.tar.gz

Tags: r, version, package, readxl

Im trying to install an old version of Readxl (**readxl_0.1.1.tar.gz**), with both this options:

```
# Try Number 1
packageurl <- 
"http://cran.rproject.org/src/contrib/Archive/readxl/readxl_0.1.1.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")

#Try number 2
install.packages("C:/Users/.../readxl_0.1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = 
"source")
```

The two options give me the following error:

```
Warning: comando ejecutado 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R- 
34~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" 
SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' 
SHLIB="readxl.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o XlsWorkBook.o XlsWorkSheet.o 
XlsxWorkBook.o XlsxWorkSheet.o benchmarks.o endian.o ole.o xls.o xlstool.o 
zip.o"' tiene estatus 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'readxl'
```

my R version is:

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "4.2"

$year
[1] "2017"

$month
[1] "09"

$day
[1] "28"

$`svn rev`
[1] "73368"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)"

$nickname
[1] "Short Summer"
```

Comment: My guess looking at the error message (and making some assumptions about what it actually would have said in English) is that you do not have a proper set of Rtools installed for R 3.4. I would point out as well that you didn't actually include the message that described the error. The message you included only had a warning. Try reading up on installing Rtools: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+install+rtools+%5Br%5D

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i think the error is this one: "ERROR: compilation failed for package 'readxl'" because then it trys to install the previous version of readxl.
I will try with Rtools.

Comment: You _always_ need to install archived packages from source, and you often need to have Rtools installed. Not always on the second part but it will be so for any Windows package whose DESCRIPTION file  says `NeedsCompilation: yes` (which the current version of 'readxl' does.)